# Disable App Nap via Javascript/HTML

Tags: safari, audio, javascript, app-nap

Is there a message that could be sent in a way that at least Safari, if not other browsers, understands that tells Mavericks not to engage App Nap? I have an HTML5 pseudo-MIDI rendering app (i.e., sends individual notes out as mp3 audio) which plays back fine on Safari so long as it's in the foreground, but when focus is lost Safari/OS X does not send back sufficient calling information to play the notes at their appropriate times.  What I'd love is something like:

```
if (window.disallowAppNap !== undefined) {
    window.disallowAppNap = true;
}
this.playScore(callbacks = {end: function() { 
        if (window.disallowAppNap !== undefined) {
           window.disallowAppNap = false;
        }
    } }
);
```

From a web search, it seems that the answer to this is "Nope," but maybe someone on the OS X or Safari dev. team will see this and think, "that's a great idea!" I've looked through the Web Audio API but can't see anything connecting to App Nap.

Comment: I know I'm a little late on this one, but maybe nowadays Electron would be the way to go.

Comment: Ah! you're probably referring to https://electronjs.org/docs/api/power-save-blocker#powersaveblockerstarttype -- it's a bit too late for my app to rebuild on electron, but i'll see if there is a way to use their code.

Comment: oh, this is for desktop apps, I'm looking for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, not currently. JavaScript/HTML can't directly control App Nap in Safari or any other browser on OS X.

Comment: thanks. Given your reputation, I'm tempted to mark this as Accepted immediately, but I'll give it a day to see if someone's come up with a clever trick. If I haven't marked it by then, please feel free to prod me.

Comment: @michael Haha, it's not like I'm in need of reputation :) Feel free to leave this unaccepted until an actual answer comes up in the future

Comment: till then, my thanks. I think that sending a continuous <audio> signal at the minimum possible volume is helping, but it's a bad way of coping.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert, yes, audio element works for me, it prevents going Firefox to go to App Nap even if audio is muted but it takes some additional CPU usage. Sort of compromise... So I have used some 1sec mp3 in loop with very low bitrate.